# Redirect page with parameter

Tags: wpf, list, redirect

I have a wpf application C#

I want to make a redirection from `Page1.xaml` to `page2.xaml` passing a client list as a parameter that I recover it and  to display in `page2.xaml`

Thanks

Comment: Context of this question is not clear. Show some codes you have so far f.e. how you *redirect* to page2 without passing parameter, or passing parameter with single value. Then maybe we can help further with how to pass parameter with multiple values

Answer (score 0):

```
page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("page2.xaml?parameter=clientlist", UriKind.Relative));
```